# Time Series Data Prediction (on delta with shift(1))

Tags: pandas, time-series, prediction, forecasting, arima

I have time series data in increasing order, like the data given below:

```
**dataset 1**
----------------------
date    value
----------------------
date1   10
date2   12
date3   13
date4   15
----------------------
```

If I make predictions using standard models, I'm getting good result without any issues.

My question is: can I take a delta of the data with shift(1) and use the resulting series for prediction? This will have the DELTA values like those below:

```
**dataset 2**
----------------------
date    value
----------------------
date1   0
date2   2
date3   1
date4   2
----------------------
```

Am I making the good data into 'white noise'? What are your suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking deltas of time-series is part of the [Box-Jenkins Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins_method). If the deltas are not stationary, then further analysis of them can show trend and seasonality, for example. This is exactly the case when differencing does not create white noise.

That being said, it might not be necessary for you to develop this from scratch. Libraries such as [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html), for example, contain ?AR?MA? models (that is auto-regressive moving-average models, possibly integrative). You might want to check [`statsmodels.tsa`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/tsa.html) in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, (Trying out with statsmodels.tsa only). What if I take the deltas on time-series and predict using AR, MA, ARMA or ARIMA ?  Hope ARIMA takes delta and use it as one of the component, Am I doing something wrong in taking deltas for ARIMA ?

Comment: **  in taking deltas  ( of my data set and use in ARIMA )

Comment: @M.Gopal The models in `statsmodels.tsa` already handle the deltas. It's probably better if you don't apply them to the deltas.